# How to read files from HDFS using spark streaming and save them to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, pyspark, hdfs, jupyter-notebook, spark-streaming

Is there a way, using spark streaming to read files from HDFS (e.g. JSON)  and then save them to elasticsearch?

I am able to read JSON files, make a pyspark dataframe and then save it to an index in elasticsearch but is it possible to do this using spark streaming? I want every file that gets saved to HDFS, to gets saved in elasticsearch too.

I am using Jupyter Notebook, ElasticSearch 6.3.0 and spark 2.3.0 with Python

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @sailesh
Right now I am reading the documentation of elasticsearch and spark streaming, but, I have not figured out anything yet

Comment: Its possible in Scala/Java, not sure about in Python. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html#spark-streaming-write